# Gaussian Distribution C#

Tags: c#, gaussian, normal-distribution, mathnet-numerics

So I want to distribute some points using the normal distribution. I cant figure it out. The goal is to have numberOfInstances many Points. I wanna have 5 intervals that have a different number of points Total = numberOfInstances and it should be spreaded like the gaussian distribution...

Not quite sure if I made that understandable...

For example 20 Instances in 5 intervals => |..|....|........|....|..|

My problem:

So what i want to get of the code is just a list of doubles that adds up to 1 (so i can multiply with number of instances and get the above...) which it doesnt at the moment. Where did i go wrong?

```
    using MathNet.Numerics.Distributions;
public static List<int> GaussianDistribute(int numberOfInstances)
        {
            

            List<int> gaussianDistribution = new();
        List<int> numberOfInstancesList = new();
        List<double> intervalsList = new();
        for (int i = 0; i<numberOfInstances; i++)
        {
            numberOfInstancesList.Add(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<numberOfInstances; i+= (numberOfInstances/5))
        {
            intervalsList.Add(i);
        }
        double average = intervalsList.Average();
        double sumOfSquaresOfDifferences = intervalsList.Select(val => (val - average) * (val - average)).Sum();

        double sd = Math.Sqrt(sumOfSquaresOfDifferences / intervalsList.Count);

        List<double> probabilities = new();
        for (int i = 0; i< intervalsList.Count; i++)
        {
            double interval = intervalsList[i];
            double p = Normal.CDF(average, sd, interval);
            
            probabilities.Add(p);
        }
        List <double> gaussProbabilities = new();
        
        foreach (var prob in probabilities.Select((value, i) => new { value, i }))
        {
            if (prob.i > (probabilities.Count/2.0))
            {
                gaussProbabilities.Add(1-probabilities[prob.i]);
            }
            else
            {
                gaussProbabilities.Add(probabilities[prob.i]);
            }
        }[...multiply...]}
```

Comment: Can you normalize the values? Take each one and divide it by the sum. The final set of values should add up to 1.

Comment: I'm guessing the "points" (or the list of doubles) you're talking about are the PDF of the distribution. If so, what do the intervals represent for you? Do you have [something like this](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-68-95-99-7-rule-for-a-normal-distribution-b7b7cbf760c2) in mind?